# How to render a comma separated list of links in a single Material-UI DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'd like to display a list of links in a single cell in a row in a DataGrid. For example, in a column called `Orders` I'd like to list a comma separated list (or separated in some otherwise visually pleasing way, maybe a bulleted list) of links. Here's what I have so far:

```
const columns = [
    {
      field: "orders",
      headerName: "Orders",
      width: 500,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        const orders = params.value
        const ordersWithLinks = orders.map(
          (order, index) => LinkToOrderPage({ order_id: order, key: index }), // Returns a <Link> component
        )
        return ordersWithLinks
      },
]
```

This gets me close, but each link is displayed one after the other with no space in between. How do I fix this?

Comment: Would wrapping `orderWithLinks` in something like a `<div>` and styling that work? You could then apply CSS styles to it like `display: flex` and `gap: 8px`.

Comment: If you want bullet points, you could try wrapping the result `LinkToOrderPage` with `<li>` and wrapping `orderWithLinks` in `<ul>`. For commas, wrap the result of `LinkToOrderPage` with a `<Fragment>` and conditionally add commas.

Comment: I gave that a shot and it basically just puts a space between each link. Definitely an improvement, but not quite there yet I think.